# how to concatenate all the values of a variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, stringbuilder

I am storing output of JDBC request in Jmeter Variable - "temp_num".
Now I need to concatenate all the values stored in this variable in form of 'a','b','c'......'n'. I did try aggregation withing SLQ script too, but there we have a limit on string length, that's why I would like to probably use something like string builder, but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JDBC result set into a string using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the code like :

```
temp_num = vars.getObject("temp_num");
result = new StringBuilder();

for (Object row : temp_num) {
    iter = row.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        pair = iter.next();
        result.append(pair.getValue());
        result.append(",");
    }
}

vars.put('result', result.toString())
```

However be aware that there is a [limit of the number of characters in Java String](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-limits-of-String-Size-and-BigInteger-in-Java) so make sure not to exceed it.

[More information:](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/) Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter